# Error org.apache.tiles.TilesException: Attribute not found

Tags: java, xml, jsp, struts2, tiles

I'm working on a web project and I use Tiles to have multiple JSP's in one JSP.

I've encountered a problem where I get `TilesIOException`.

I have this JSP with the name: `mainpage.jsp` which contains all the JSP's for header, body and footer.

My body here should also contain some other JSP's and therefore I'm trying to use tiles in that as well with no luck.

Here's the structure and the XML code in tiles:

```
mainpage.jsp
----header.jsp
----body.jsp(mainpageBody.jsp)
--------bodybox1.jsp
--------bodybox2.jsp
--------bodybox3.jsp
--------bodybox4.jsp
----footer.jsp
```

**`tiles.xml`:**

```
<definition name="mainpage" extends="mainpageLayout">
<put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome" />
<put-attribute name="body" value="/mainpage/mainpageBody.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="mainbox0" value="/bodybox1.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="mainbox1" value="/bodybox2.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="mainbox2" value="/bodybox3.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="mainbox3" value="/bodybox4.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="mainpageLayout" template="/mainpage.jsp">
<put-attribute name="title" value="Template" />
<put-attribute name="header" value="/mainpage/header.jsp" />
<put-attribute name="body" value="/mainpage/body.jsp" />
<put-attribute name="footer" value="/mainpage/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

**Here is my `mainpageBody.jsp`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.*,java.util.*"%>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showRegisterUserPage() {
        $(".frontpageBodyContent").load("showRegisterPageRegisterAction");
    }
</script>
<div class="frontpageBodyContent">
    <div id="frontPageContentDiv">
        <table border="0" style="width:100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="bodybox1">
                            <tiles:insertAttribute name="bodybox1" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="bodybox2">
                            <tiles:insertAttribute name="bodybox2" />
                        </div>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="bodybox3">
                            <tiles:insertAttribute name="bodybox3" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="bodybox4">
                            <tiles:insertAttribute name="bodybox4" />
                        </div>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

`WEB-INF` folder contains: `lib` folder, `tiles.xml` & `web.xml`. `lib` folder doesn't contain anything.

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value=",action"/>
    
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles"
                class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        
        <action name="*MainAction" method="{1}" class="com.x.web.action.MainAction">
            <result name="mainpage" type="tiles">mainpage</result>
            <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
        </action>
        
        <action name="*RegisterAction" method="{1}" class="com.x.web.action.RegisterAction">
            <result name="registeruserpage" type="tiles">registeruserpage</result>
            <result name="redirect" type="redirect">${redirectUrl}</result>
        </action>
    


    <action name="registrering" method="showRegisterUserPage" class="com.x.web.action.RegisterAction">
        <result name="registeruserpage" type="tiles">registeruserpage</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

**`web.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <javaee:display-name>X</javaee:display-name>
    <context-param>
        <javaee:param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG
        </javaee:param-name>
        <javaee:param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</javaee:param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <javaee:listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
        </javaee:listener-class>
    </listener>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**I get exceptions:**

`org.apache.tiles.TilesException`:

```
ServletException including path '/templates/mainpage.jsp'.

org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/content/mainpage/mainpageBody.jsp'.

org.apache.tiles.TilesException: Attribute 'bodybox1' not found.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post the contents of JSP page(s). What version of plugin you use?

Comment: I will do that when I come home from work!

Comment: There is no attribute with `bodybox1` name in your configuration.

Comment: @AleksandrM I have `<tiles:insertAttribute name="bodybox1" />` in a div in mainpageBody.jsp

Comment: Exactly my point. You are trying to insert attribute but you don't have declaration for it.

Comment: @AleksandrM I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Where and how should I declare the attribute? You mean like a definition for each bodybox in tiles.xml?

Comment: @RomanC now I have updated with my mainpageBody.jsp!

Comment: @user2099024 I needed the full JSP file posted. And you didn't answer my question.

Comment: @RomanC Now I've updated with the whole JSP. My tiles version is 2.0

Comment: @user2099024: Yes that what you should do.

Comment: @user2099024 Post a `struts.xml`, `web.xml`, and `WEB-INF` content including `lib` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>X</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>tilesDefinitions</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
        <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and check that `tiles.xml` in `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: I will try this when I get home today and let you know if it worked, thanks. My tiles.xml is in the web-inf yes.

Comment: I get the same problem with this solution.

Comment: I might just skip this idea of having JSPs in those divs, it doesn't make any difference anyway. If you know the solution you could write it, but don't waste your time otherwise. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: If you have convention plugin on classpath remove it, rebuild ,redeploy, restart. You'd better post the folder structure and contents of web root.